# Xcode8 UIScrollView not laying out subviews correctly

Tags: uistoryboard, xcode8

I am updating my project to use Xcode8 and it's giving me some trouble. For some reason UIScrollView isn't laying out the subviews correctly. Here is a screenshot of the storyboard:

[image]

And then this is what is rendered on the phone:

[image]

Not exactly what I want. If I change the UIScrollView to a UIView. Then it renders as I would expect:

[image]

This seems to me to be a bug with xcode8, which so far, I am not very impressed with. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you please attach this project (or another sample project that reproduces this issue) to a new bug at bugreport.apple.com for us to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the height constraint to your CollectionView (to any value you need). It will fix layout problem in iOS 10.

Comment: I'm not using constraints. I have autolayout turned off.